# JS: Defining laravel route inside JS Function with parameter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I am going to send an AJAX request inside a Laravel Blade. This is my code:

```
function submitForm(userId) {
var ajaxUrl = '{!! route("user-role-update", '+userId+') !!}'
        $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: ajaxUrl,
            data: {
                _token: "{!! csrf_token() !!}",
                'newRoles': userRoleTableData
            },
```

In the controller, I returned the userId to check if the userId is passed to the URL or not, but the result was not returning the userId:

```
{ 
  "msg": "Something wrong while deleting the old roles--",
  "id":"+userId+",
  "isUserRoleSaved":false
}
```

Instead of returning the userId, it returns the variable "userId" with the "+" from JS script. How can I solve this?

Comment: This is basic logic. PHP gets executed before JavaScript. PHP is on the server, JS is on the client and only executed when the user submits the form. Let's say that the PHP function returns `https://example.com/{userId}`. What PHP sees when it's rendering is "+userId+", when in fact that's only defined in the client. Either change your implementation on the server side to not require a userID URL at render or send 2 AJAX requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function submitForm(userId) {
var url = '{{ route('user-role-update', ':userId') }}';
url = url.replace(':userId', userId);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: url,
        data: {
            _token: "{!! csrf_token() !!}",
            'newRoles': userRoleTableData
        },
```

Comment: Well at least it solved my problem. Works perfectly, thank you.